# Redirect using PHP and mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to redirect any path to *index*. It's working but how can I make it to report subfolders?

**Example 1:**

Redirect from `example.com/profile/<PROFILE-ID>/<PROFILE-NAME>`

to `index.php?path=profile&id=<PROFILE-ID>&name=<PROFILE-NAME>`

**Example 2:**

Redirect from `example.com/admin/`

to `index.php?path=admin`

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?path=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now my assets doesn't load.

Comment: @User3302325 Try adding **<base href="/">** to the head section of your webpage to solve relative links.